# How does webpack find and resolve my fonts in node_modules?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, font-awesome

I've created a `vue.js` application using the `webpack template`. Later I added `FontAwesome`. Surprisingly resolving the fonts works and the font URI points to a /static subdirectory (like http://localhost:8080/static/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.af7ae50.woff2).

My loader looks like this:

```
{
  test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
  loader: 'url-loader',
  options: {
    limit: 10000,
    name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
  }
}
```

Of course, I also required the css for FontAwesome.

While I am happy that this works out-of-the-box, I'd like to understand what's going on here under the hood. How does `webpack` resolve that and how does it avoid collisions?